# Failed to retrieve bundle prices for a steam game with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer, steam

I'm writing a code to get the title and price of a game's bundles, separating the title and price for each bundle, but it returns that bundle_price is null.

```
import puppeteer from "puppeteer";

async function handleAgeRestriction(p) {
  await p.evaluate(() => {
    const select = document.querySelector("#ageYear");
    const options = select.querySelectorAll("option");
    const selectedOption = [...options].find(
      (option) => option.text === "1900"
    );

    selectedOption.selected = true;
  });
  await p.click("#view_product_page_btn");
}

async function getDataFromGame() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto("https://store.steampowered.com/app/271590/");

  await handleAgeRestriction(page);

  await page.waitForSelector(".apphub_AppName");
  // await page.waitForSelector(".game_purchase_price");
  await page.waitForSelector("div.game_area_purchase_game > h1");
  await page.waitForSelector("div.discount_final_price");

  const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const data = document.querySelectorAll('.game_area_purchase_game');
    const game = [...data].map((bundle) => {
      const bundle_title = bundle.querySelector('div.game_area_purchase_game > h1').innerText;
      const bundle_price = bundle.querySelector("div.discount_final_price").innerText;

      return {
        bundle_title,
        bundle_price,
      }
    })
    return game;
  });

  console.log(result);

  await browser.close();
}

getDataFromGame();
```

I find the error strange because if I replace "bundle" with "document", it correctly retrieves the price, but it will always be the same price

```
 const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const data = document.querySelectorAll('.game_area_purchase_game');
    const game = [...data].map((bundle) => {
      const bundle_title = bundle.querySelector('div.game_area_purchase_game > h1').innerText;
      const bundle_price = document.querySelector("div.discount_final_price").innerText;

      return {
        bundle_title,
        bundle_price,
      }
    })
    return game;
  });

  console.log(result);
```

(This is an example of how it does NOT throw me an error, but the price will be the same for all bundles.)

Comment: You're using `bundle_price = document.querySelector` rather than `bundle_price = bundle.querySelector`, so that incorrectly always selects from the document root rather than within the container. Style nitpick: use `$$eval('.game_area_purchase_game', data => ...)` as shorthand for `evaluate()` that runs `[...document.querySelectorAll("...")]` as the first operation.

Comment: Yes, I understand that I need to use bundle_price = bundle.querySelector. However, even though there is a div element with the class "discount_final_price", it does not return the value of the bundle. It's as if the div doesn't exist. Even when trying the method you recommended, it seems to work the same way. It returns the title of the bundle but not the price.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I think I read too fast and misunderstood your code blocks. Sorry about that. OK, looking at the page, the first section doesn't have a price. Instead, there's a dropdown for purchase options. `bundle.querySelector("div.discount_final_price")?.innerText` will make your existing code work, but it'll leave that first option blank since there's nothing there for that selector. What sort of output do you want for that element since it has multiple prices?

Comment: Thanks for your help again, ggorlen. If I manage to solve the problem, I'll let you know in the post!

Comment: @ggorlen I solved the problem. I thought `const bundle_price = bundle.querySelector("div.discount_final_price").innerText;` Would be specific enough, but it wasn't. The problem was solved by using a more specific selector: `const bundle_price = bundle.querySelector("div.game_area_purchase_game > div > div > div > div > div").innerText;`

Comment: Thanks for that, although [super-specific selectors](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#misusing-developer-tools-generated-selectors) like that are prone to break. There should be a better way to grab the price.

Comment: Indeed, I will investigate the root cause of the problem. I will update the post with a more detailed explanation of the problem and the solution.

Comment: Ah, I see it now! I hadn't read your edited comment yet. Your method for validating the existence of the div with the class discount_final_price is really clever! I really appreciate your help and apologize for any inconvenience I may have caused unknowingly haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error (`Error [TypeError]: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'textContent')`) is that some bundles don't have `.discount_final_price` elements. Instead, they have a dropdown that lets you select one of a few options with different prices.

Instead of assuming that `.discount_final_price` is always present, you can use a condition to handle the possibility that it isn't and grab the dropdown list:

```js
const result = await page.$$eval(
  ".game_area_purchase_game",
  els =>
    els.map(bundle => {
      const bundle_title = bundle
        .querySelector("h1")
        ?.textContent.trim();
      const bundle_price = bundle.querySelector(
        ".discount_final_price"
      )?.textContent;

      if (bundle_price) {
        return {
          bundle_title,
          bundle_price,
        };
      }

      bundle
        .querySelector(
          ".game_area_purchase_game_dropdown_selection"
        )
        .click();
      return {
        bundle_title,
        bundle_prices: [
          ...bundle.querySelectorAll(
            ".game_area_purchase_game_dropdown_menu_item_text"
          ),
        ].map(e => e.textContent)
      };
    })
);
```

Output will now look something like:

```js
[
  {
    bundle_title: 'Buy Shark Cash Cards',
    bundle_prices: [
      'Tiger Shark: GTA$250,000 - $4.99',
      'Bull Shark: GTA$600,000 - $9.99',
      'Great White Shark: GTA$1,500,000 - $19.99',
      'Whale Shark: GTA$4,250,000 - $49.99',
      'Megalodon Shark: GTA$10,000,000 - $99.99'
    ]
  },
  {
    bundle_title: 'Buy Grand Theft Auto V: Premium Edition & Great White Shark Card Bundle',
    bundle_price: '$19.80'
  },
  {
    bundle_title: 'Buy Grand Theft Auto V: Premium Edition & Megalodon Shark Card Bundle',
    bundle_price: '$36.40'
  },
  {
    bundle_title: 'Buy Grand Theft Auto V: Premium Edition',
    bundle_price: '$29.98'
  }
]
```

You could process this list further and use `e.textContent.split(" - ").at(-1)` to extract the price from each dropdown item.